# Using java substrings to format a string

Tags: java

How do I format a string to have dashes in between using substring to look like `xxx-xx-xxxx`? I have tried the following code and it only adds the dash after 3 characters:

```
String str = "123665985";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
builder.insert(3, '-');
String dashes = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 builder.insert(3, '-').insert(6,'-');
```

Eg:

```
String str = "123665985";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
builder.insert(3, '-').insert(6,'-');
String dashes = builder.toString();
System.out.println(dashes);
```

Out put:

```
123-66-5985
```

Here you want to add `-` for index `3` and `6`. Then you need to add `-` for both place.

Comment: If you would add a little explanation of what you changed and why this would be perfect ;-)

Comment: I did what Ruchira did just a little differently    String str = "123665985";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
builder.insert(3, '-');
builder.insert(6, '-');
builder.toString();